# paypal nightmare

Tags: php, html, paypal-ipn

I have included an example I am trying to test here but since I am new to paypal, and I have no idea how to debug the paypal, sandbox is not helping me much either :(

It looks like the payment has been processed and accepted, All I have to do now is update mysql table, on the line marked below just under `"if($payment_amount==10.00&&$payment_currency=='GBP'){"`. I have tested my mysql on phpmyadmin and it works like a charm it's just something else may be wrong up here :(

**Paypal Button**

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business"  value="[email]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name"  value="New Subscription" />
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name"  value="<?php echo  $arr['user']['fname']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name"  value="<?php echo  $arr['user']['lname']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address1"  value="<?php echo  $arr['user']['add1']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address2"  value="<?php echo  $arr['user']['add2']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="city"  value="<?php echo  $arr['user']['town']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="zip"  value="<?php echo  $arr['user']['postcode']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email"  value="[client_email]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code"  value="GBP" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
    <input type="hidden" name="recurring" value="1" />  
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00" />  
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y" />
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $arr['user']['id'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return"  value="<?php echo site_url.'account/' ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"  value="<?php echo site_url.'account/' ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url"  value="<?php echo site_url.'account/ipn.php' ?>" />
</form>
```

**Paypal IPN handler**

```
<?php 
// UPDATED LINE BELOW
mail("[myemail]", "PP",'initiated', "From:support@paypal.com"); 
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
// $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
// $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$item_name              = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number            = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status         = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount         = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency       = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id                 = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email         = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$business               = $_POST['business'];
$payer_email            = $_POST['payer_email'];
// $payer_email             = $_POST['payer_email'];


if (!$fp) {
    // echo 'Error 101 23';
    // die();
} else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            $data['paypal_receivers_email']     = '[email]';
            if($payment_status=='Completed' && $receiver_email == $data['paypal_receivers_email'] &&$receiver_email){
                if($payment_amount==10.00&&$payment_currency=='GBP'){
                    //successfully// now update db :)// <== this is where im strugling it does not seem to come down here at all.
                }
            }
        // check the payment_status is Completed
        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        // process payment
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation

        }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}

?>
```

Comment: I think sandbox includes a log/debug feature, I remember seeing that there but not very sure, you may check.   check also and see if the email to debug works on another page, maybe even better try to log in a file using file_put_contents, then check log, sometimes emails go to bulk folder you don't want to be distracted by a side problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to debug, as I did:

In each step, put email() with details which came from paypal (by post) and others. Log (mail yourself) each success, error and it will give you your problem source. for example, put

```
 mail("yourmail@mail.com", "PP", $res, "From:support@paypal.com");
```

just after declaring your variable

Comment: I have tried that with the script given from https://www.paypaltech.com/sg2 when I use the IPN sandbox, it will not work :( i receive no emails whats so ever :(

Comment: as I said, make debugger for yourself, log EVERY step of IPN handler and PayPAl's action and their responses. You'll get into source of your problem easier

Comment: I don't think you understood me, I could put ` mail("yourmail@mail.com", "PP", $res, "From:support@paypal.com")` on the very top of the page of ipn handler, and it does not email me even that, if I access same url directly it works,

Comment: I tried your answer, my ipn url, if i Put it on sandbox and test it, I don't receive an email, if however I access the ipn from my browser, it does work, this is why it's bizarre

Comment: su just put it to your database/file/whatever. Just debug it

Comment: ok the problem was that the url I had put was the alias url as suppose to direct url to the ipn. However the `mail();` answered my debugging question so thumbs up :) thnx mate

Answer (score 0):

Is site_url a constant?

```
<input type="hidden" name="return"  value="<?php echo site_url.'account/' ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"  value="<?php echo site_url.'account/' ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url"  value="<?php echo site_url.'account/ipn.php' ?>" />
```

If it is not you are missing a $ or a () if it's a function.

Have you double checked that the full url is being returned in the form html source?  If it works in the browser it seems that paypal may not be getting the correct return url for IPN.